# Devise ERROR: Auth token has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Trying to signup in my RoR webapp give me the Devise Message **"Auth token has already been taken"** 
Also, the webapp have an API and works fine, doesn't give any message, this only happen when I'm trying to use the HTML view.

user_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# DELETE /users/:id.:format
  def destroy
    # authorize! :delete, @user
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      accessible = [ :name, :email ]
      accessible << [ :password, :password_confirmation ] unless params[:user][:password].blank?
      params.require(:user).permit(accessible)
    end
```

User.rb

```
  validates :auth_token, uniqueness: true
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  before_create :generate_authentication_token!
  def generate_authentication_token!
    begin
      self.auth_token = Devise.friendly_token
    end while self.class.exists?(auth_token: auth_token)
  end
```

logs

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-30 09:31:46 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (12.9ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."auth_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.haml (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (3.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.haml (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 132ms (Views: 117.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)


Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-30 09:32:00 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"20w9AXmACwggvPocKfLBdrxQRasT5OiaC7niuzooBBm3BAp8xkN6VLWyxZLRoLIpFPEIIdkxZRd9CCwsJxkeUA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"hola@x.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = '' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'hola@x.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.2ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."auth_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.haml (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.haml (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 232ms (Views: 134.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery/jquery-bb5529929fa5581a780a38ecb7470f2c.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-30 09:32:00 -0500
```

Comment: in your user.rb file you use [ validates :auth_token, uniqueness: true ],and you cann't create a user with same token twice.  I think thats why you getting this error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the following 
1) Open Rails console

```
rails console
```

2) Get the total count of users

```
user = User.all
user.count
```

this should be 1

3) Get the user and check the auth token

```
user = User.last
user.auth_token
```

auth token would be an empty string which is the reason your command is failing as the user doesn't have valid auth token

4) Create a valid auth token for the user

```
user.auth_token = Devise.friendly_token
user.save
```

It would create a valid auth token for the user and save it

5) Now you can run your commands and it would work perfectly

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you already have users in your db without auth_token,
use  Devise.friendly_token to update those users with a token